# Annotated Dataset for Evaluating Text Coherence

Tags: nlp, dataset, topic-modeling

I need a human-annotated dataset for evaluating text coherence methods. I read many papers but none of them provides such a dataset (except for the recent neural network-based models).

Is there any publicly available dataset where the coherence of text is scored by experts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I am aware of for coherence specifically.  A lot of the research into coherence has focused on matching coherence scores to human-judged topics, where humans are tasked with scoring the coherence of a topic in general.  Coherence has been found to correlate better to human judgments than measures like perplexity, but it is geared toward topic coherence and not overall text coherence.  In doing our own research, we normally have to get domain experts to do bespoke coherence evaluations of topics.

Comment: @rchurch4 I see, thanks for your answer.